# List to non-nested JSON to pass to a template

Tags: flask

I am querying my database and assigning all the results to a variable called `reports`

```
results = db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM reports")
reports = [dict(r) for r in results]
```

If I print this variable, I have:

```
[{'id': 1, 'type': '{"organization":"Dunder Mifflin","reported_at":"2015-04-21","created_at":"2015-04-22","inventory":[{"name":"paper","price":"2.00"},{"name":"stapler","price":"5.00"}]}'}, {'id': 2, 'type': '{"organization":"MOM Corp.","reported_at":"3015-08-24","created_at":"3015-08-23","inventory":[{"name":"bending unit","price":"2000.00"},{"name":"stapling unit","price":"50.00"}]}'}, {'id': 4, 'type': '{"organization":"Flowers Inc.","reported_at":"2017-11-19","created_at":"2017-11-23","inventory":[{"name":"Flower pot","price":"2.00"},{"name":"Roses, 24","price":"50.00"}]}'}, {'id': 5, 'type': '{invalid_json'}]
```

I want to rendered the variable `reports` in my template and do a `for loop` to iterate across all reports.

```
@app.route('/allreports')
def allreports():
  return render_template("allreports.html", reports=reports)
```

**HOWEVER**

Since it is a list, I cannot do a for loop.

For example I cannot print the "organization" for each report.
How can I do so?

If I do a for loop I can only print the ID and type but not other elements inside of `type`

```
{% for report in reports %}
  {{report['id']}
  {{report['type']}
{% endfor %}
```

If I do `{{report['type']['organization']}}` nothing is printed out. I think because the nested dict is a string, not a dict.

```
'type': '{"organization":"Dunder Mifflin","reported_at":"2015-04-21","created_at":"2015-04-22","inventory":[{"name":"paper","price":"2.00"},{"name":"stapler","price":"5.00"}]}'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the value of `type` is valid JSON. A quick solution would be to override the string value with a parsed JSON in the form of a dict.

```
import json

for r in reports:
    r['type'] = json.loads(r['type'])
```

Now you can do `report['type']['organization']` inside the template.

Comment: I tried: `results = db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM reports")


for r in results:
    r.type = json.loads(r.type)


reports = [dict(r) for r in results]`but now I get: `AttributeError: 'RowProxy' object has no attribute 'type' - r.type = json.loads(r.type)`

Comment: I think the problem is also that JSON should be in double quotes while I have single quotes after `type`: 'type': '{"organization".....

Comment: I fixed the answer. Quotes should be fine because the single ones constitute a string and its content is valid json with double quotes.

Comment: Your answers is good but the iterations should be on `reports` nor `results`. Can you please edit it?